# How to use regular JSON interpretation inside of a Jackson custom JSON deserializer

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind, jackson2

I am writing a custom deserializer and not sure how to best handle the following case:

I am deserializing something that looks like this:

```
{
  "someProp": {
    "name": "some string"
    "value": ****** can be anything here, including string, number, object, etc. ******
  }
}
```

The object I am mapping this to has this:

```
public class ObjectToMapTo {
    String name;
    Object value;
}
```

In my code, I have the `JsonNode` that represents the `someProp` field. I can obviously extract the `JsonNode` of the `name` and easily convert it to `String` with `JsonNode.asText()`.

However, how do I deal with the `value`? `JsonNode` does NOT have a method for `asObject()`. Surprisingly, it only has `isObject()`. Do I have to go through a `switch` statement to figure out what type of of a thing it is just so I can call the correct method like `asLong()` or `asText()`?

But even if I do the `switch` statement, what if the `nodeType` is `Object`. Then what? How do I get that `JsonNode` to just be a regular Java `Map` like it would regularly if I were to use the `ObjectMapper` without a custom deserializer?

Comment: Can you please explain what do you meant object, can it also be json or array ?
If its going to be only Number/String, you could very well use String all the time and then typecast internally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid you have to do some custom deserializing and switching/iffing here.

> JsonNode does NOT have a method for asObject(). Surprisingly, it only has isObject().

Yes. It is not a problem to determine if the value is an object since object nodes start with `{`. But to what specific class instance it can be constructed is impossible to guess. That should not be surprising.

> what if the nodeType is Object. Then what? How do I get whatever is specified for value in JSON

If there was a field - say  `type` - that tells the type you could do it easily in your custom deserializer. So if you have power to add it then you could give there the whole class name to instantiate to in your deserializer.

Otherwise I think the best you can do would be to instantiate arbitrary object as an instance of a `Map` or just as a `TreeNode`.

You could annotate field `value` for the deserialiser like (so not the parent):

```
@Getter @Setter
public class ObjectToMapTo {
    private String name;
    @JsonDeserialize(using =  MyDeserializer.class)
    private Object value;
}
```

In your deserializer after you have checked that it is not array nor value, something like:

```
Object o;
TreeNode valueTreeNode = jp.readValueAsTree();
// check if array or valueNode
// but if is object
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
o = om.treeToValue(valueTreeNode, Map.class);
return o;
```

Comment: So, if `getNodeType` is `OBJECT`, then what would I be able to do to get it into a `Map`, which is what I meant, but didn't explain that well (will update the question).

Comment: @user1902183 updated answer hope it clarifies a bit

Comment: In your example, `jp` is still pointing to the parent node. The parsing needs to be done on one of the fields, not the parent node. How would I accomplish that?

Comment: @user1902183 example is not complete you actually need to create custom deserializer and parse the parent node, field by field. I'll update answer later.

Comment: what's your opinion on instead of doing all that, just do `parser.readValueAs(ObjectMatchingActualJSONFormat)` and then simply convert the matching actual JSON format POJO into the POJO that I need. Would that be a bad practice?

Comment: @user1902183 i would not say it as a bad practice, not necessarily. But I'm not sure how that would go. I mean that you would need to parse source json first to know the actual json format? That is why the JsonTree is constructed at first place. There might be a way, though.

Comment: @user1902183 Got a bit mixed about that "parent" deserializing, of course you can annotate only field `value` and make the deserializer  to touch only that :) see update.